# html2canvas and jsPDF not save image of external host

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jspdf, html2canvas

In my code I'm trying to capture everything inside the div including styles and images.
The images if they belong to the current host are saved without problems, if they belong to an external host they are not saved ...

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.0.272/jspdf.debug.js"></script>

<div id="printDiv">
  <h2>Hello World</h2>
  <p>
    this content will be printed.
  </p>
  
  <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/33/b8/69/33b869f90619e81763dbf1fccc896d8d.jpg" />
</div>
<button type="button" id="pdfDownloader">Download</button>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    //pdf   
    $("#pdfDownloader").click(function(){
    
        html2canvas(document.getElementById("printDiv"), {
            onrendered: function(canvas) {

                var imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
                console.log('Report Image URL: '+imgData);
                var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'mm', [297, 210]); //210mm wide and 297mm high
                
                doc.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 10, 10);
                doc.save('sample.pdf');
            }
        });

    });
    
    
})
</script>
```

What alternative can I use to save images with external links in my pdf?

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this with jQuery & canvas2image

```js
$(function() { 
    $("#pdfDownloader").click(function() { 
        var imgURL = $("#printDiv").find('img').attr('src');
        
        html2canvas($("#printDiv"), {
            onrendered: function(canvas) {
                var context= canvas.getContext("2d"); // returns the 2d context object
                var img = new Image() //creates a variable for a new image

                img.src= imgURL; // specifies the location of the image
                context.drawImage(img,0,50); // draws the image at the specified x and y location
                // Convert and download as image 
                theCanvas = canvas;
                document.body.appendChild(canvas);

                // Convert and download as image 
                Canvas2Image.saveAsPNG(canvas); 
                $("#img-out").append(canvas);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/releases/download/0.4.1/html2canvas.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/canvas2image/base64.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/canvas2image/canvas2image.js"></script>


<div id="printDiv">
  <h2>Hello World</h2>
  <p>
    this content will be printed.
  </p>
  
  <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/33/b8/69/33b869f90619e81763dbf1fccc896d8d.jpg">
</div>

<button type="button" id="pdfDownloader">Download</button>
```

Comment: Man i tried your code but return "Canvas2Image is not defined" and the image is only duplicate on the page and download of pdf not work..how can i do? Thanks

Comment: Anyway, I tried a similar route trying to print the image on the canvas first and then download the pdf but it always returns white space

Comment: When i click not save image or pdf on my computer...

Comment: You cant do this with javascrip. User need to save it manually